# When both biometrics are enrolled i.e. face id and fingerprint, local auth shows both

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, fingerprint, face-id

I have a login page. User can login through face id or finger print. I am using local auth package 1.1.11 (because Biometrictype.fingerPrint and faceId works here after that it uses BiometricsType.weak and BiometricsType.Strong) to local perform authentication. I am facing an issue that when both biometrics are enrolled in my device i.e. face id and fingerprint, local auth shows both biometrics when i taped on fingerprint sensor or face id.

static Future<bool> authenticate() async {

List<BiometricType> availableBiometrics =
await _auth.getAvailableBiometrics();

```
final isAvailable = await hasBiometrics();
if (!isAvailable) return false;

if (availableBiometrics.contains(BiometricType.fingerprint)) {
  try {
    return await _auth.authenticate(
      biometricOnly: true,
      stickyAuth: true,
      useErrorDialogs: true,
      localizedReason: 'Scan Fingerprint to Authenticate',
     
    );
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
    myToastError('Please add finger print first');
    return false;
  }
}
return Future.value(true);
```

}

static Future<bool> authenticateFaceId() async {

List<BiometricType> availableBiometrics =
await _auth.getAvailableBiometrics();

```
final isAvailable = await hasBiometrics();
if (!isAvailable) return false;
if (availableBiometrics.contains(BiometricType.faceId)) {
  try {
    return await _auth.authenticate(
      biometricOnly: true,
      useErrorDialogs: false,
      sensitiveTransaction: false,
      stickyAuth: true,
      localizedReason: 'Scan Face to Authenticate',
      
    );
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
    myToastError('Please add face id first');
    return false;
  }
} else {
  return Future.value(false);
}
```

}

Comment: Which issue are you facing with biometric?

Comment: if i tapped to fingerprint it should logged me in through fingerprint. but it shows face id first and then fingerprint.

Comment: I used biometrics in my project - can you please describe your problem in detail

Comment: Like you set fingerprint but you got faceid first?

Comment: My problem is that, when both fingerprint and face id is enrolled, it shows face id first despite i tapped on fingerprint and then shows fingerprint sensor to login.

Comment: Means, your problem is that i set fingerprint and when i came back its promote with face id not on fingerprint correct?

Comment: No, let me clarify !
I have enrolled both face id and fingerprint in my android phone.
Now on my login page i have given 2 buttons.
one for logging in through face id and one for fingerprint.
So problem is when i tapped on fingerprint button, it open login through face id first and then shows fingerprint dialog. I don't want faceid to be called on tap of fingerprint

Comment: Will update you soon

Comment: Please change your option for finger print to

Comment: authenticated = await localAuthentication.authenticate(
          localizedReason: StringConstants.fingerText,
          options: const AuthenticationOptions(
            stickyAuth: true,
          ),
        );

Comment: Set only sticky auth in the fingerprint @Bunny

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid it didn't worked.

Comment: authenticated = await localAuthentication.authenticate(
      localizedReason: "Scan your finger to authenticate",
      options: const AuthenticationOptions(
        stickyAuth: true,
        
      ),
    );

Comment: if i give above code they asking me for both auth finger and face

Comment: authenticated = await localAuthentication.authenticate(
      localizedReason: "Scan your finger to authenticate",
      options: const AuthenticationOptions(
          stickyAuth: true, biometricOnly: true, sensitiveTransaction: false),
    );

Comment: Or if give all of above option they are asking me for face only

Comment: not working :(( @rahulVFlutterAndroid

Comment: Also, package issues they were not written any issue regarding this, also i saw your issue on github which you posted today on issue of package :(